# need user to land on billing page from url in opencart, need already loaded shopping cart

Tags: php, opencart

I want to redirecting a user from a mail by hyperlinking him to a billing page on opencart KEEPING THE PRODUCT VALUE Already uploaded in the cart..
Instead of showing cart I just want the user to see billing, fill the form & checkout..
I have thought of creating a product in the shopping cart & redirecting the user to its billing page but if i use the billing page of that product THE COOKIE VALUE EXPIRES when used from an external link..

Is there a way to land a customer directly to a billing page keeping the product already loaded in cart? (I only have one product.)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a small modification to checkout controller.

Let's say You will have links in Your newsletter like this one:

```
http://your.eshop.com/index.php?route=checkout/checkout&add_product=1&product_id=10&pieces=1
```

Then immediately at the begining of the file `catalog/controller/checkout/checkout.php` (before the line `if ((!$this->cart->hasProducts() ...` You would have to check if there is `if(isset($this->request->get['add_product']) && $this->request->get['add_product'])` and if so, do `$this->cart->add($this->request->get['product_id'], $this->request->get['pieces']);`

The whole code could look like:

```
public function index() {
    if(isset($this->request->get['add_product']) && $this->request->get['add_product']) {
        $this->cart->add($this->request->get['product_id'], $this->request->get['pieces']);
    } // END OF MODIFICATION, the next code is already in checkout.php controller

    // Validate cart has products and has stock.
    if ((!$this->cart->hasProducts() && empty($this->session->data['vouchers'])) || (!$this->cart->hasStock() && !$this->config->get('config_stock_checkout'))) {
        $this->redirect($this->url->link('checkout/cart'));
    }
```

Should You wish to make user buy more than one product, the link should look like

```
http://your.eshop.com/index.php?route=checkout/checkout&add_product=1&product_id[]=10&pieces[]=1&product_id[]=45&pieces[]=2&product_id[]=37&pieces[]=1
```

Now the code should look like:

```
if(isset($this->request->get['add_product']) && $this->request->get['add_product']) {
    foreach($this->request->get['product_id'] as $i => $product_id) {
        $this->cart->add($product_id, $this->request->get['pieces'][$i]);
    }
} // END OF MODIFICATION
```

What this piece of code would do? Directly after clicking on the link and opening on the browser the code would add the desired product(s) to the cart and will continue further as usualy thus the process would be the very same as if the user would go to the products detail page, click on "Buy" button and click on "Checkout" link somewhere in Your eshop.